# Huawei Watch 2 NFC FEATURE not available?. Android Wear 2.0

Tags: android, nfc, wear-os, huawei-mobile-services

In short:
**On the Huawei Watch 2 it seems like *NFC* is available and enabled but *NFC_FEAUTURE* is not, hence nfc is not working properly.**

Trying to develop the ability to simply read and display NFC tags on the Huawei Watch 2 raises some difficulties:

```
mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this,nfcPendingIntent, nfcIntentFilter, null);
```

raises the error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

That implies the FEATURE_NFC is not available.
In MainActivity onCreate():

```
mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);  //NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter
if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
  // Check if device supports NFC
  Log.i("NFC","Your device supports NFC");
}
// Check if NFC is enabled
if (mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Log.i("NFC","NFC is Enabled");
}
if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)) {
// Device compatible for NFC support
   Log.i("NFC", "Device compatible for NFC support"); 
}
```

shows in console

```
... I/NFC: Your device supports NFC
... I/NFC: NFC is Enabled
```

but not

```
... I/NFC: Device compatible for NFC support
```

In other words

`mNfcAdapter !=null` and
`mNfcAdapter.isEnabled() == true` but   `(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC) == false`

How is this possible?

Btw. my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

see also [Android NFC Tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278) and a similar post [NFC Android wear (Huawei watch 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391741/nfc-android-wear-huawei-watch-2-0)

What am I doing wrong? Is NFC on the Huawei Watch 2 somehow locked or disabled?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: I am trying something similar on the LG Sport Watch (with Google Pay and NFC)... would you mind sharing your test code so I can quickly verify?  Maybe we can bring a case forward to Google together.

Comment: For your reference... on LG Watch Sport, NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this) returns null, and getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC) return false.  No luck there.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [documentation](http://www.channelpostmea.com/2017/07/03/review-huawei-watch-2/), NFC feature is supported in Huawei Watch 2 and it also features Android Wear 2.0.

However, the error [`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) means that the method isn't implemented yet by the framework authors, so you might contact the support team for clarifications. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17312302/5832311).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Im about to get in contact with the Huawei developer support. I was hoping that there is someone else with the same problem. I will post the result of the support process.

Comment: The Huawei developer support has no phone number and doesn't answer emails. Anybody else, please?

Comment: @RobinBöhm have you managed to make any progress? I'm now facing the same problem.

Comment: @sintho sadly not. Did you? I'm trying to face the issue again atm.

Comment: @RobinBöhm not with the Huawei Watch 2. I've switched to the Sony SmartWatch 3 SWR50, for which a patched kernel with enabled NFC exists. For my small study project this is good enough, but it's obviously not a solution for 'real-world' projects.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to create a prototype which makes use of the NFC feature on a Huawei Watch 2 you could circumvent this bug by forcing the feature flag to true.

First create a function which is able to set a static property through reflection:

```
fun setStaticValue(className: String, fieldName: String, newValue: Any) {
    val field = Class.forName(className).getDeclaredField(fieldName)

    field.setAccessible(true)

    val oldValue = field.get(Class.forName(className));

    field.set(oldValue, newValue);
}
```

Then use the function just before you are calling a method which tests for the feature flag like this:

```
setStaticValue("android.nfc.NfcAdapter", "sHasNfcFeature", true)
```

I don't think this hack will be accepted for released apps though, but I was able to recognize tags using this method.

I've also send a bug report to Huawei, so let's hope they will fix it.

For more information using reflection see: http://blog.sevagas.com/?Modify-any-Java-class-field-using-reflection