# NFC Reader mode on Android Wear

Tags: nfc, android-wear-2.0

I would like create one Android Wear app to interact with ISO14443 contactless card via NFC, we tried different Android Wear watches with NFC and support Android Pay (HCE), but we always got UnsupportedOperationException like mentioned in this thread [Huawei Watch 2 NFC FEATURE not available?. Android Wear 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437854/huawei-watch-2-nfc-feature-not-available-android-wear-2-0) 
Does anyone know any Android Wear watch suupporting NFC reader mode?
Thanks in advance.